# Create mechanism for updating key value pair

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, dictionary

The following json I want to create mechanism in python for updating key value pair.

```
   defaults={
          "price_std":1.0,
          "ncoen_ece":{
          "iz_default":"EST",
          "Iz_options"=["US/EST","Indian", "Pacific"]
}

"filters":{
           "remove_hording":False,
           "remove workdays":True,
           "remove states": {
              "CA": True,
              "GA": False,
        },
    },
}
```

I am trying to load it in dictionary, loop through dictionary to check if key is present, if key is not present look through value of array.
I have tried the following code:

```
def update_dict(d, **kwargs):
    for arg, value in kwargs.items():
        if arg in ('izoptions', 'states', 'holidays'):
            for k, v in d.items():
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    update_dict(v, **{arg: value})
                elif k == arg:
                    d.update({arg: value})
        else:
            d.update({arg: value})
```

I am trying to load it in dictionary, loop through dictionary to check if key is present, if key is not present look through value of array.
i have tried the following code

```
def update_dict(d, **kwargs):
    for arg, value in kwargs.items():
        if arg in ('izoptions', 'states', 'holidays'):
            for k, v in d.items():
                if isinstance(v, dict):
                    update_dict(v, **{arg: value})
                elif k == arg:
                    d.update({arg: value})
        else:
            d.update({arg: value})
```

Comment: No, we cannot; Stack Overflow is not a coding service or a tutorial site.
Please repeat [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).
“Show me how to solve this coding problem” is not a Stack Overflow issue.  You have to make an honest attempt, and *then* ask a *specific* question about your algorithm or technique.

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question]( https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). This usually suggests that what you need is time with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow. Best of all, each tutorial will teach you a collection of related techniques, rather than merely solving the immediate problem.

Comment: Can anyone correct me on this?

Comment: Much better.  Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.